# Laravel page not found at create function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Recently I started programming using Laravel as a framework. Everything goes fine, but I tried to write a create script with the following message at runtime:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

That's after posting Accept in the Create form, I already have created Index, Show, Update and delete functions successfully. So the route to my controller is correct, the file exist ... I'm totally stuck and can not see what incorrect.

Please help.

I didn't redirect the public folder so I'm still using the full path with no problem at the other modules (/gymmgr/public/lockers).

I send you the code:

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')    

@guest
@else
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Lockers</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-1 d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-sticky">

            <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
              <span>Acciones</span>
              <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
              </a>
            </h6>

            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <span data-feather="home"></span>
                   <span class="sr-only"></span>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/gymmgr/public/lockers/create">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span>
                  Nuevo
                </a>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="h5">Catálogo</h1>
            <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
              <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Exportar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">

      <tr>
        <th>Clave del locker</th>
        <th>Ubicación</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($lockers as $locker)
      <tr>
        <td> <a href="/gymmgr/public/lockers/{{ $locker->idLocker }}">{{ $locker->strClaveLocker }} </a>></td>
        <td>{{ $locker->strUbicacion }}</td>
      </tr>

      @endforeach

    </tbody>
  </table>




        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

@endguest
@endsection
```

LockersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Locker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LockersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // 
        $lockers = Locker::all();
        return view('lockers.index', ['lockers'=>$lockers]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('lockers.create');

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        /*
        if (Auth::check())
        {*/
            $locker = Locker::create(
                ['strClaveLocker'=>$request->input('strClaveLocker'),
                    'strUbicacion'=>$request->input('strUbicacion')
                ]
            );

            if($locker)
            {
                return redirect()->route('lockers.index')->with('success','Locker creado con éxito');
            }
     //   }*/
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Locker  $locker
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Locker $locker)
    {
        //
        $locker = Locker::find($locker->idLocker);
        //$locker = Locker::where('idLocker', $locker->idLocker)->first();
        //echo e($locker->idLocker);

        return view('lockers.show', ['locker'=>$locker]);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Locker  $locker
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Locker $locker)
    {
        //
        $locker = Locker::find($locker->idLocker);
       if ($locker)
        {
        return view('lockers.edit', ['locker'=>$locker])->with('success', 'Locker encontrado'); 
        };
        return view('lockers.edit', ['locker'=>$locker]);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Locker  $locker
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Locker $locker)
    {
        //
        $lockerUpdate = Locker::where('idLocker', $locker->idLocker)->update([
            'strClaveLocker'=>$request->input('strClaveLocker'),
            'strUbicacion'=>$request->input('strUbicacion')]);
        if ($lockerUpdate)
        {
            return redirect()->route('lockers.show',['lockers'=>$locker->idLocker])
                ->with('success', 'Locker actualizado correctamente'); 
        }

        return back()->withInput();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Locker  $locker
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Locker $locker)
    {
        //
        $findLocker = Locker::find($locker->idLocker);
        if($findLocker->delete())
        {
            return redirect()->route('lockers.index')
                ->with('success','Locker borrado exitosamente');
        }
        return back()->withInput()->with('error','El locker no pudo borrarse');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')    


@guest
@else


<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Locker') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    </form>
                      <form method="post" action="{{ route('lockers.create') }}">

                          {{ csrf_field() }} 
                          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="locker-clave">Clave del locker<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input  placeholder="Clave del locker"
                                    id="locker-clave"
                                    required
                                    name="strClaveLocker"
                                    spellcheck="false" 
                                    class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="locker-ubicacion">Ubicación del locker</label>
                            <input  placeholder="Ubicación del locker"
                                    id="locker-ubicacion"
                                    required
                                    name="strUbicacion"
                                    class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input  type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary"
                                    value="Aceptar" 
                                    />
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


@endguest

 @endsection
```

The route

web.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('lockers','LockersController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create form has:

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('lockers.create') }}">
...
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
```

So you are sending a `PUT` request to your create route.  [As the docs describe](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers), the `.create` route the `resource` declaration sets up is expecting a `GET` (check the table of actions it sets up).  So that request will fail with a 404 as there is no matching route set up.

Also, though confusingly named, the `create` route is for displaying the create form, *not* saving data you've entered into that form.  So you should not be submitting data to your create route.

You need to:

- Change your form action to point to your `store` route: `... action="{{ route('lockers.store') }}`
- Remove the form method spoofing, `store` expects `POST` which is what you'll get by default without any spoofing.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. It certainly confused me, cause I was working with a good, big and popular example from youtube, and there, everything seems to work like in the code of the create function I sent. But I had the clue that told me that, It had to be done using store. Thanks a lot, again.